# if condition is not working with string variables in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a model `Book` which contains a `CharField: 'category'` which describes the genre of book and I want to display the information of books according to their genre.

I tried this:

```py
{% for category in categories %}
 <div class="row">
  <div class="title-section mb-5 col-12">
   <h2>Popular in {{category}}</h2>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   {% for book in books %}
    {% if book.category == '{{category}}' %}
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 item-entry mb-4">
      <a href="#" class="product-item md-height bg-gray d-block">
       <img src='/media/{{book.img}}' alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
      </a>
      <h2 class="item-title"><a href="#">{{ book.title }}</a></h2>
      <strong class="item-price">Rs. {{ book.price }}</strong>
     </div>
    {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

models.py :

```py
def main(request):
    books = Book.objects.all()
    categories = []

    for book in books:
         categories.append(book.category)

    categories = list(set(categories))

    return render(request, "index.html", {'books': books, 'categories': categories,})
```

But this is not working, it displayed only:

Popular in fiction

Popular in motivational

Popular in informative

Popular in teen

Popular in autobiography

No information of any books is displayed. I think there is problem in `if condition` please help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
{% if book.category == '{{category}}' %}
```

To this

```
{% if book.category == category %}
```